# Python letter counter error

Tags: python

Right now, I am trying to create a python program that counts the amount of times a function appears in a string.

My code is below and so is the error.

```
from collections import Counter
import string


def count_letters(word):
    global count
    wordsList = string.split(word)
    count = Counter()
    for words in wordsList:
        for letters in set(words):
            return count[letters]

word = input("what do you want to type? ")
print (count_letters(word))`
```

Error: The error is an attribue split error. If you need the exact message. Copy/paste the code.

Comment: *"If you need the exact message. Copy/paste the code."* Please post the full traceback error here for people to see. Don't expect people to run your code, especially since some people answer from computers where they may not have Python installed.

Comment: I guess this question is about Python 3? Python 2 has `string.split()`. Posting a traceback would surely help :)

Answer (score 5):

This line is not correct

```
wordsList = string.split(word)
```

You would just do

```
wordsList = word.split()
```

Without giving any delimiter to `split`, this will split by default on whitespace.

Edit: To count just a particular letter, there is already such a string method, conveniently named `count`

```
>>> 'test'.count('t')
2
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I just need to figure out how to count a particular letter